# How to redirect to URL from webhook

Tags: http, go, redirect, https

I have developed a Go app. A webhook has been integrated. I have been successful in getting the payload (JSON format) from the webhook. However, I can't seem to do a redirect.

**Step 1:** User make payment at page /live.

**Step 2:** Upon successful payment, my payment processing company send a POST request to my webhook (/paymentsucess). payment function is called. In payment(), I was able to decode the JSON data that was POST to /paymentsucess and fmt.Println accordingly.

```
http.HandleFunc("/paymentsuccess", payment)
```

Now in Step 3, I want to redirect the user (which is still seeing /live) to a page (/thankyou) on successful payment. In the JSON posted to the webhook, there is a payment status field. I was able to do a if condition to check that this field has value "success". In such case, fmt.Println("redirecting to thank you"). This is all good. Then in the next line (inside payment() function), I added the below

```
http.Redirect(w, r, "/thankyou", http.StatusSeeOther)
```

I was expecting the current client page (which is still at /live) to redirect to /thankyou. But this is not happening.

How should one handle webhook redirects?

**UPDATE**
When the webhook post successfully to payment(), I receive the below response and request

**response**

```
&{0xc00029c1e0 0xc0002a0700 0xc000386300 0x1120e20 false false false false 0 {0 0} 0xc000386200 {0xc0003a67e0 map[] false false} map[] false 0 -1 0 false false [] 0 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0] [0 0 0] 0xc0003481c0 0}
```

**request**

```
&{POST /paymentsuccess HTTP/1.1 1 1 map[Accept:[*/*] Accept-Encoding:[gzip] Content-Length:[3162] Content-Type:[application/json] User-Agent:[Omise/2019-05-29] X-Datadog-Parent-Id:[6096593905335487199] X-Datadog-Sampling-Priority:[1] X-Datadog-Trace-Id:[8016780258334486542] X-Forwarded-For:[52.74.199.175] X-Forwarded-Proto:[https]] 0xc000386300 <nil> 3162 [] false d4e7c3fca000.ngrok.io:443 map[] map[] <nil> map[] [::1]:60999 /paymentsuccess <nil> <nil> <nil> 0xc000386340}
```

**UPDATE 2**
Thanks to @gipsy I as able to implement the steps he suggested. Right up to Step 4. I have a goroutine who poll query mysql database every two seconds to check for payment status. Once so, I was able to fmt.Println accordingly. So that confirms that I can confirm payment. BUT... I have trouble redirecting the current client page (user is at /live)...

```
func startPolling1(ShopName, SourceID, Status string) (string, bool) {
    for {
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        Amount, Result := queryDBForPaymentSuccess(ShopName, SourceID, Status)
        if Result == true {
            fmt.Println("found result")
            fmt.Println("no more polling")

            //HOW DO I DO A REDIRECT HERE? http.Redirect won't work because of error "superfluous response.WriteHeader call"

            break
        }
    }
    return Amount, Result
}

func livemode(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
if !alreadyLoggedIn(req) {
        http.Redirect(res, req, "/", http.StatusSeeOther)
        return
    }
    Shop = getUser(res, req)

    if req.Method == http.MethodPost {
       //Some codes here
       go startPolling1(Shop.Shopname, Charge.Source.ID, "successful")
       //Some codes here
     }
   }
 tpl.ExecuteTemplate(res, "golive.html", data1)
}
```

Comment: What _is_ happening?  Can you show some actual debug output?  I.e. if you do a query with `curl -v`, what output do you see?

Comment: @Flimzy I'm not sure. I am a new programmer so is still very amateur. I have updated my post with the response and request. The POST request to /paymentsuccess is good. But I just can't redirect my user to /thankyou. I was thinking, if the right way is to set my webhook to be /live?

Answer (score 0):

First of all the web-hook request coming to your server is totally independent from the request you get from your user. So a redirect you try in the web-hook handle is not going to work

I think there could be many way to handle this. One way could be:

1. Let the user submit the payment at /live( which you are doing)
2. As part of completing the payment set status for that payment request in your db , say pending.
3. When the web-hook arrives update the status to completed.
4. Keep polling for the payment status from /live and when it see completed redirect user to wherever you want.
5. You could use an ajax call to your server for the status check.

Comment: Thanks! i did what you suggested. All good until step 4 :( I have a goroutine who check the database every 2 seconds. On finding the payment status to be successful, I can do things like fmt.Println("sucess"). But i can't do any redirect. I have Updated my code above. http.Redirect don't work as there will be the "superfluous response.WriteHeader call" error ....

Comment: The goroutine is happening on your server side. You cannot redirect a client from there. Some how from your client side (/live page or whatever) need to check the status via an ajax call or even give a button for user to click say 'check payment status' and handler on ur backend to handle the status check from the client and in the handler you should be able to do the re-direct.